# brew install fbsimctl - SHA256 mismatch

Tags: shell, homebrew

I am trying to set up [`wix/detox`](https://github.com/wix/detox) and one of the requirements is to install `fbsimctl`, via homebrew.

Here's my console output:

```
==> Installing fbsimctl from facebook/fb
==> Downloading https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl/tarball/v0.4.0
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl/legacy.tar.gz/v0.4.0
########################################################################     100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 5d2ed56047f2b4b3f5f0804545c6730876be2372a834e70bc88a4cb9d4253e19
Actual: 4a8bb8aed15f756aeb57e4a1f8724e40a3dfaa27740ae1644021386ab64bd9fb
Archive: /Users/dan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/fbsimctl-0.4.0.0
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

I then ran:

`rm -rf /Users/dan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/fbsimctl-0.4.0.0`

And then:

`brew update && brew cleanup && brew cask cleanup`

Then once more:

`export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO && brew install fbsimctl`

But I still get the aforementioned console output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) of the file is not matching the formula, you can verify by downloading the file:

```
$ curl -L -O https://github.com/facebook/FBSimulatorControl/tarball/v0.4.0
```

And later geting the checksum:

```
$ $ openssl dgst -sha256 v0.4.0 
SHA256(v0.4.0)= 4a8bb8aed15f756aeb57e4a1f8724e40a3dfaa27740ae1644021386ab64bd9fb
```

I would suggest creating a pull request (if you know/trust and ensure that the sources are correct) but better contact the developers https://github.com/facebook/homebrew-fb/blob/master/fbsimctl.rb regarding this issue, the main idea of the checksum is to guaranty data integrity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It hadn't crossed my mind to check GitHub. There's already a PR with the intention of fixing it.